# Unity project button doesn't want to work

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't for the life of me figure out why my button doesn't work! The same button does work in the main game. I removed the script from the main game and added an On click event but nothing happens. What is the absolute stupid thing I am missing here? xD

[Snip of my Unity screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC5rx.png)

Comment: Where is the PlayGame Function located and could you show the PlayGame Function code?

Comment: Playgame is located on the startmenu. This is the code
`public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void PlayGame ()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
}`

Comment: Just to make sure, have you included all your scenes into the build / do you get any error messages when you click on the button?

Comment: Yes, only scenes are menu and game, and they are both in there. No errors in log, just... nothing
Alomost feels like it's masked by something but it's almost at the bottom of the tree

Comment: The TextTitle element in your hierarchy may be blocking touches. Since its after the buttons if its rect transform is large it may be overlapping. Check if its the case and if it is you can uncheck Raycast Target for the Text element.

Comment: That was my first guess as well, but the text tile only covers the title portion: https://imgur.com/a/NztLkUL

Comment: Do you get an error in the console about the index number at all?

Comment: The console stays completely empty, will try to put out a debug log in there see what happens

Comment: Added a Debug.Log into the script and nothing appears on the Log. It's like the button click is not registering...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know what was wrong, so I started from scratch, and then I noticed something. I deleted the EventSystem in the original and that was the problem!